# Adding two animations to one button?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

In WPF I want to be able to add two animations to say for example a button in XAML, I have got it to animate once when the button is clicked, is it possible to run another animation once it is clicked again?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to alternate between these animations ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's possible. First animation has to end before though. Just call button.BeginAnimation(anotherAnimation) after firstAnimation.Completed event has fired.

Comment: so nothing in XAML then, ill try and figure out how to write it in C# then thanks